# how to do history.push for multiple parameter with multiple value (array) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React router, onClick of the dropdown value (which is multi selection) I'm trying to push value to the parameter, value I'm passing is an array but somehow in the URL it's showing only a single value. How do I send multiple values as one parameter?

Could anyone suggest a solution?

```js
     var study_dashboard=['abc','xyz','pqr']
       history.push(
          `/dashboard/filter?name=${study_dashboard}`
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to run as you expect here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-do-history-push-for-multiple-parameter-with-multiple-value-array-in-rea-zrsnm). I see the URL update to `"/dashboard/filter?name=abc,xyz,pqr"`. What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `JSON.stringify` to convert the array into a JSON notation string.

```js
var study_dashboard=['abc','xyz','pqr']
history.push(
    `/dashboard/filter?name=${JSON.stringify(study_dashboard)}`
);
```

Comment: No, if I use like this  only url is displying in browser there is no paramter with value

Comment: @sssss just edited, does that help?

Comment: hi, ya it's working thank you